# How to get variable from the FileReader.onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, openlayers

```
var startAnimate;
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (evt) => {
moveFeature = function (event) {
                    var vectorContext = event.vectorContext;
                    var frameState = event.frameState;

                    if (animating) {

                        var elapsedTime = frameState.time - now;
                        // here the trick to increase speed is to jump some indexes
                        // on lineString coordinates
                        var index = Math.round(speed * elapsedTime / 1000);

                        if (index >= route.length) {
                            stopAnimation(true);
                            return;
                        }
                        var currentPoint = new ol.geom.Point(route[index]);
                        var feature = new ol.Feature(currentPoint);

                        vectorContext.drawFeature(feature, geoMarker.getStyle());
                    }
                    // tell OpenLayers to continue the postcompose animation

                }

            startAnimate = function startAnimation() {
                if (animating) {
                    stopAnimation(false);
                } else {
                    animating = true;
                    now = new Date().getTime();
                    speed = 5;
                    startButton.textContent = 'Cancel Animation';
                    // hide geoMarker
                    geoMarker.setStyle(null);
                    // just in case you pan somewhere else

                }
            }

            function stopAnimation(ended) {
                animating = false;
                startButton.textContent = 'Start Animation';

                // if animation cancelled set the marker at the beginning
                var coord = ended ? route[route.length - 1] : route[0];
                /** @type {ol.geom.Point} */ (geoMarker.getGeometry())
                    .setCoordinates(coord);
                //remove listener
            }
 }
 var test = '<label for="speed">speed:&nbsp;<input id="' + inputID + '" type="range" min="1" max="100" step="1" value="10"></label><button id="' + buttonID + '" onclick={startAnimate}>Start Animation</button>'
```

All the variable is found in the `reader.onLoad()` and couldn't put test variable as well as other variables inside `reader.onLoad()` function get it to work.
I am using the test variable to create marker animation button for the uploaded file

I am new to this language so explanation is welcome